# 32bit calculation for 16bit dsPIC33F takes 460 instructioncyclese?

Tags: dspic

I'm using a 16 bit Timer as hardware delay for the function `delay_ns(UINT32 ui32_delay_val_ns);`. Within the function the `delay_val` is been divided by `Tcy`. The timer runs at `Tcy`, which is 25ns (instruction cycle time at 40MHz), so every tick (or TMR4 val bit) would be 25ns.

As a good software engineer should do, I ran some tests with the function and I wonder about something.

See timings: delay_ns: 10, a=2 b=27 c=485 d=494 e=504

I asked for 250ns, which is 10 TMR4 ticks of 25ns.

a is after BOOL bStart = 1 and TMR4.ON = 1; (2 cycles is nothing strange).

b = TMR4 val after I devide the previous to 16 bit casted ui 32 bit val value by 25;

c = TMR4 val (direct after b!!) when I devide the original 32 bit val by 25.

As you see, using 16 bit vals costs 25 instruction cycles (maybe a lot too?), but using 32 bit costs +450 cycles? So in other words, a simple division of a 32 bit val takes 11.5 us!!

Specially because this is the dsPIC33 variant from Microchip, which has some improvements (pipelines, double ACU's etc). 
I know it's a 16bit MCU, but why does it take so much cycles?

Comment: Made some changes to make the question more readable.

Comment: Datatypes?  Are you doing integer or floating-point division?  Either way, you're talking about software division, which is expected to be quite slow.  It should be quite a bit faster if the denominator is a compile-time constant and the compiler can replace division with Montgomery multiplication,  You do have optimizations enabled, right?

Comment: Hi, No it's not floating point devision, but integer. I don't have optimization enabled at the moment, which I could try, because of I have to check if all elements then still works as expected. Because it's a commercial application, I don't have the freedom I like to have to "play" with the compilersettings for the best results. It just was a question coming up in my mind while testing&running the app.